# Quorum failure - Failed to decode message from payload

Tags: proof-of-stake, quorum, memory

We use in our project -JP Morgan Quorum (Ethereum based) bloackchain - with istanbul voting mode. We have 4 nodes (3 of them are validators - hard coded, nonchangable)

And from time to time (unpredictable - but approximately once per several hours) - and the less nodes we use - the more rare the failure occurs. (for 7 nodes - once per two days). Also quorum node may consume up to 1Gb of memory after sending a Transaction to a contract, deployed on Quorum. (Transaction just sets two uint storage variables)

Log looks like this:

```
INFO [05-07|10:14:12] Successfully sealed new block lock number=254599 hash=a0f9f2…c10589
INFO [05-07|10:14:12] :hammer: mined potential block n number=254599 hash=a0f9f2…c10589
INFO [05-047|10:14:12] Commit new mining work deduped=254600 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=2.774ms
ERROR[05-07|10:18:42] Failed to decode message from payload address=0xd8Dba507e85F116b1f7e231cA8525fC9008A6966 e
rr="unauthorized address"
```

And I have two questions:
 1. Did somebody have the same issue and how resolved it?
 2. Did somebody use Quorum in production, or it is not stable enough
    for that purpose?
 3. Have somebody guess or idea about such kind of failure?
 4. Is it normal for Quorum to consume a lot of memory

I know, questions are "common and abstract". But I need, besides tha issue solution, to have your opinion and view on Quorum.

And our genesis.json file, if it helps (all the nodes listed there, we, of course, have configured and launched)

```
{
    "alloc": {
     "0xed9d02e382b34818e88b88a309c7fe71e65f419d": {
        "balance": "1000000000000000000000000000"
      },
      "0xca843569e3427144cead5e4d5999a3d0ccf92b8e": {
        "balance": "1000000000000000000000000000"
      },
      "0x0fbdc686b912d7722dc86510934589e0aaf3b55a": {
        "balance": "1000000000000000000000000000"
      },
      "0x9186eb3d20cbd1f5f992a950d808c4495153abd5": {
        "balance": "1000000000000000000000000000"
      },
      "0x0638e1574728b6d862dd5d3a3e0942c3be47d996": {
        "balance": "1000000000000000000000000000"
      }
    },
    "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "config": {
      "homesteadBlock": 1,
        "eip150Block": 2,
        "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "eip155Block": 3,
        "eip158Block": 3,
      "istanbul": {
        "epoch": 30000,
        "policy": 0
      },
      "isQuorum": true
    },
    "extraData": "0xd783010702846765746887676f312e392e33856c696e75780000000000000000f8c9f83f948157d4437104e3b8df4451a85f7b2438ef6699ff94b912de287f9b047b$
    "gasLimit": "0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0",
    "difficulty": "0x1",
    "mixHash": "0x63746963616c2062797a616e74696e65206661756c7420746f6c6572616e6365",
    "nonce": "0x0",
    "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "timestamp": "0x00"
  }
```